# SQL-SERVER Query is taking too much time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, indexing

I have this simple query but it is taking 1 min for just 0.5M records even all columns mentioned in select are in Non Clustered index.

Both tables have approx 1M records and approx 200 columns in each.

Does having lots of records in table or having lot of index causing the slowness.

```
SELECT catalog_items.id,
       catalog_items.store_code,
       catalog_items.web_code AS web_code,
       catalog_items.name AS name,
       catalog_items.name AS item_description,
       catalog_items.image_thumnail AS image_thumnail,
       catalog_items.purchase_description AS purchase_description,
       catalog_items.sale_description AS sale_description,
       catalog_items.taxable,
       catalog_items.is_unique_item,
       ISNULL(catalog_items.inventory_posting_flag, 'Y') AS inventory_posting_flag,
       catalog_item_extensions.total_cost,
       catalog_item_extensions.price
FROM catalog_items
     LEFT OUTER JOIN catalog_item_extensions ON catalog_items.id = catalog_item_extensions.catalog_item_id
WHERE catalog_items.trans_flag = 'A';
```

Update: execution plan showing index missing it the same index is already there. Why?

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194842/discussion-on-question-by-devesh-sql-server-query-is-taking-too-much-time).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not convinced that the plan is wrong currently, on the basis that you mention selecting 500k rows, out of a table of 1m rows. Even with an index as suggested by others, the selectivity of that index is pretty weak, from a tipping point perspective (https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/the-tipping-point-query-answers/ ) - even with 200 columns I wouldn't expect 500k out of 1m rows per table to result in index seeks with lookups, a full scan would be faster in the CBO's view.

The missing index question - if you look closely its not just suggesting the index on trans_flag, it's suggesting to index the field and then `INCUDE` a number more. We can't see how many it's suggesting to include, but I would expect it to be all of them in the query and it's basically suggesting you create a covering index. Even in an NC Index Scan scenario this would be faster to scan than the base table.

We also have no information about physical layouts as yet, how the page is constructed, level of fragmentation etc, or even what kind of disks the data is on and overall size. That image_thumbnail field for example is suggestive of a large row size overall, which means we are dealing with off page storage into LOB / SLOB.

In short - even with a query plan, there is no 'easy' answer here in my view.

Comment: spot on topicstarter imagine 500K random disk i/o requests (500K * 10ms = 1.38888889 hours) to use indexes vs one random disk i/o (1 * 10ms) to find the table and stream the table data at ~80 Mb/s assumming standard HDD here..

Comment: all other columns are already included in trans_flag non clustered index but it is showing index missing message when i am using the trans_flag check in where clause in not showing message when used in join itself.

Answer (score 1):

For this query

```
select . . .                                    
from catalog_items ci left outer join
     catalog_item_extensions cie
     on ci.id = cie.catalog_item_id
where ci.trans_flag = 'A'
```

I would recommend an index on `catalog_items(trans_flag, id)` and `catalog_item_extensions(catalog_item_id)`.

Comment: same indexes are there in table but still slow.

Comment: @Devesh . . . Your *explain plan* says the index is missing.

Comment: @GordonLinoff it technically says an index of those fields + a number of others being included is missing.

Comment: Also the "non null filter check" (not using IS [NOT] NULL) filter should be in the `ON` clause this will return as a `INNER JOIN` instead.as the filter is used on the left joined table